# Suppress Popup command window during WIX created installer

Tags: iis, wix, window, command

I have command which sets the application pool in IIS, during installation this pops up the command window for few seconds which i don't want to be shown. Need to execute it quietly.

Following is the command written in wix file.

```
CustomAction Id="XSTAppPool32" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:"XSTAppPool" /managedPipelineMode:Classic  /managedRuntimeVersion:v2.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See the WiX documentation regarding [Quite Execution Custom Actions](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm). You can try the following snippet. You may need to tweak the property *QXSTAppPool32_Cmd* as it contains the command you want to run. I just adapted the sample in the WiX help to your question, but my syntax may not be completely correct.

```
<CustomAction Id="QXSTAppPool32_Cmd" Property="XSTAppPool32"
              Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd&quot; set apppool /apppool.name:&quot;XSTAppPool&quot; /managedPipelineMode:Classic  /managedRuntimeVersion:v2.0" Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="XSTAppPool32" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
.
.
.
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="XSTAppPool32_Cmd" After="CostFinalize"/>
    <Custom Action="XSTAppPool32" After="TheActionYouWantItAfter"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```